# Web API - OWIN TokenEndPointPath not found 404 on IIS

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I just tested a working Web.Api named "WebApiServizio1" protected with a OAuth2 BearerAuthentication (Owin implementation) and it's been deployed on the root of my IIS WebServer.

I would like to change the current webserver configuration moving the "WebApiServizio1" web.Api inside a new website WEBAPI. So I can host more then one api (with the same host and port).

**IIS:** WEBAPI webSite Port:80 (AppPool: Integrated, 4.0)

[image: Expected IIS Configuration]

**PROBLEM**
But when I try to autenticate with the OWIN Middleware I can't obtain the Token, I get a "404 - not found" response trying to reach the TokenEndpointPath.

**Recap:**

http://localhost/WebApiServizio1/ HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden CORRECT!
http://localhost/WebApiServizio1/oauth/token/ HTTP 404.0 - Not Found - :(

**This the current Owin.Startup configuration:**
[image: Startup configuration]

**Client configuration:**
[image: Client configuration]

Any ideas?

Comment: I also having the same issue.  Please post your solution.. if it is fixed.

Comment: I'm sorry no solution at the moment, our project has been stopped.

Comment: Thank you for your update, currently sub-domain(child application) won't support Token End PointPath in IIS, The only way is to create a new application and host the targeted WEB API solution.

Comment: You can have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxIly3fyoM0 . It actually tells about a package that should be there to make owin endpoints work. Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In my case in AllowInsecureHttp was set false, which was creating the error on http.

Comment: This is perhaps because you are calling the endpoint with https.

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be the trailing `/` after `token` in your `PostAsync()` call

instead write

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/oauth/token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(values)))
```

and it should work.

On a side note: when you initialize your RefreshTokenProvider with `DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(8)`, all your refresh tokens are valid until 8 hours after the programm was startet instead of 8 hours after the access token is issued.

Comment: I tried removing the trailing slash but it still returns a "not found" message.

Comment: There might be more than one problem, removing the / just solved one of them. From the information above I can't see what else is wrong. Do you run the client on the same machine as the IIS? Is IIS configured to listen on localhost or maybe just on the machine name?

Comment: No good news yet. Just to give you some updates.. it's all configured on the same machine and IIS is set up as default (localhost).

Comment: sorry, I have no more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your Owin Startup event is even firing and it attaches this url that is not found. In my case it wasn't due to wrong namespace.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I deployed directly bin\ folder, but I forgot to publish the webapi, once I did it, everything worked like a charm ^_^